# Beyond breadboards? Good ways to package simple GPIO-using project?

Tags: packages, breadboard, case

I have a couple of simple projects that use a handful of GPIO pins, a few resistors, and some sensors and LEDs.

What's a good way to package up stuff like that? Is there a premade solderable HAT-like board design allowing some components to be soldered on? Is there a case tall enough to hold a RPi along with such a board?

How about accommodating connectors for external gadgets like temperature sensors?

Comment: I have some references on stackable HATs you might be interested: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104705/how-to-tap-tee-fork-the-rpi-gpio-pins-covered-blocked-by-a-hat-phat-bo.  I am not using HATS which are expensive and not flexible.  I use proto boards and stack them into multi-story, 25cm high "towers".

Comment: Search online for "prototye PCB".  They are cheap, plentiful, easy to use, and can be cut (eg., with a hacksaw) into whatever footprint you want.  You can get these in Pi Hat format too, I believe.

Comment: You could give this type of free hand soldering a try: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/55236/how-to-make-traces-on-an-universal-pcb

Comment: Stackable HATs are a bit too small to do maintenance.  So I usually stack proto boards as towers: (1) https://imgur.com/gallery/Zy91wjC, (2) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104538/how-to-interface-more-than-10x-ads1115-a-raspberry-pi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that strip-board or perf-board will fill the gap between bread-board and a PCB (although PCBs can be relatively cheap using pooled services).

Some stripboards will have a special area on one end where you can attach a suitable dual row GPIO header (note that if you're not stacking them then you may not need a full size header, only one big enough to cover the pins you need), like this one from Roth:

[image]

Going from breadboard to stripboard is easier but perfboard can be neater and more compact, in my opinion. Also, doing double-sided builds is a challenge which ever one you choose.

[BCRobotics](https://www.bc-robotics.com/shop/raspberry-pi-b-proto-strip-board/) appear to have a Raspberry Pi specific board that might be of interest but I've not used it.

Comment: BCRobotics looks good quality, so I am going to add to my reference list.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a premade solderable HAT-like board

Yes, tons of these are on sale. A quick search using words like "prototype" and "DIY" revealed there's a board called "ModMyPi", and there are certainly others:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Sad to say the particular board in your response is discontinued. But there are, as you say, plenty of others.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not mind some soldering, 
this is an inexpensive approach:

long 40-pin stachable headers: 20 for $18 
https://www.ebay.com/itm/281394575257

6x8cm plated souble-sided proto board 20 for $14
https://www.ebay.com/itm/123934353296

Works out to $1.60 per hat.