# ADC Address in Raspberry PI

Tags: pi-4, raspberry-pi-os

How to allocate address for another ADS1115 which is an ADC in Raspberry Pi in I2C interface? The first ADC will be allocated an address of 60. But how to manually allocate the address for second ADS1115 in the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: To clarify, do you mean how to set this on the ADS1115, or on the Pi?  Because you don't do it on the latter, you do it with pins on the former, and then it will connect with a different address and be recognized as such, you don't have to do anything else.

Comment: https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/ads1115.pdf page 17 address selection

Comment: @goldilocks : The answer is your combined comments. Maybe *take the next step*? :)

Comment: @codermike: The answer is your combined comments. Maybe take the next step? :)

Comment: WRT the duplicate, the answers seem to drift toward using a multiplexor so you can add  more than 4 ADCs, the one that is most explicit about how to set alternate addresses is this one: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/119957/5538